# What regular expression pattern in the url.py do you need to match string 'title' of an object in python/django

Tags: python, django

I am having difficult matching the url pattern

I have

```
url(r'^(?P<title>)', 'pages.views.PageNameRequest')
```

and

```
def PageNameRequest(request, title):
    p = get_object_or_404(Page, title=title)
    return render_to_response('page.html', {'page': p})
```

but it just returns that

No Page matches the given query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, but you need to follow up your title param declaration with a regex to describe it.  For example, if you wanted the url to only contain one or more lower case letters, do this...

```
url(r'^(?P<title>[a-z]+)', 'pages.views.PageNameRequest')
```

but you're probably looking for something more like...

```
url(r'^(?P<title>[a-zA-Z_ ]+)', 'pages.views.PageNameRequest')
```

which would allow one or more occurances of lowercase a-z, upper case A-Z, `_` and a space.